# Raspbian Cron Job Not Working

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, raspbian

Hi I have created this cron job in the /etc/crontab file: 
`*/2 *   * * *   /usr/bin/php    /var/www/html/daily_scripts/store_all_currencies.php`.
It doesnt seem to be working I just want my store_all_currencies.php to run every 2 minutes.

I have had a look in /usr/bin/ and there doesnt seem to be a php file? This is probably the reason it isnt working. I am able to run php files from the console so it is definitely installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this for executing cron every 2 minutes, but you must have the php script inside `/usr/bin/php/ var/www/html/daily_scripts` before execute it. format => `cron format` `php path` `php filename`

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php/ var/www/html/daily_scripts/store_all_currencies.php
```

Every 2 minutes : https://crontab.guru/every-2-minutes

Comment: so just change my crontab file to contain that line of code and it should start working?

Comment: Think there is a missing space between the `php` and the `/var/www`

Comment: I have added that space :)